# Comprobar todos los checkbox seleccionados

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

quiero validar que el usuario tenga que seleccionar todos los `checkbox` para insertar algo. He logrado validar que seleccione solo uno, pero no logro que los pida todos.

Mi código `php`:

```
while ($imprime = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    $tabla .= '<tr>';
    $tabla .= '<td>' . $imprime["DESCRIPCION"] . '</td>';
    $tabla .= '<td><input class="checkRequi" name="checkRequi" type="checkbox" value=""></td>';         
    $tabla .= '</tr>';
}
```

En `jQuery` compruebo que se seleccione:

```
$(document).ready(documentoListo);

function documentoListo () {
    $("#asigBen").click(compruebaChec)
}

function compruebaChec () {

    if ($("input[name=checkRequi]").is(":checked")) { //quiero que compruebe todos seleccionados

        alert("La política de privacidad ha sido aceptada");
        return true;

    } else {

        alert("Debe aceptar la política de privacidad");
        return false;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes comparar si la longitud de la selección de todos los `checkboxs` coincide con la longitud de los `checkboxs` de esa selección que están seleccionados. Algo así:

```js
var button = $("button");

button.on("click", function () {

  var checkboxs = $("input[name='checkRequi']");
  var todos = checkboxs.length === checkboxs.filter(":checked").length;
  
  console.log(todos ? "Están seleccionados todos" : "No has seleccionado todos los checkboxs");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkRequi" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkRequi" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkRequi" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkRequi" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkRequi" />
<button>Comprueba</button>
```

Comment: gracias creo que me sirve  voy a comprobar

Comment: Excelente es justo lo que necesitaba perfecto

Comment: Me alegro, un saludo ;)

Answer (score 1):

Espero que esto te pueda ayudar. Recorre los `checkboxs` y valida si la cantidad de checkboxs es igual a la de `checkeds`:

```
function compruebaChec () {

    var checked = 0;

    $('input[name=checkRequi]').each( function () {
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            checked++;
        }
    });

    if(checked == $('input[name=checkRequi]').length){
        alert('La política de privacidad ha sido aceptada');
        return true;
    }else{
        alert('Debe aceptar la política de privacidad');
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: hola gracias en teoria realiza los mismo pero no me sirve por que los checbox son dinamicos puede ser 1 como tambien 5 ese es el problema

Comment: Este código verifica si se ha marcado al menos un `checkbox`. Debes comparar si la variable `checked` es igual a la longitud de todos los `checkboxs` para saber que se han marcado todos.

Comment: modifique la función para  validar la cantidad de checkboxs con la cantidad de checkeds, espero te sirva.

Comment: ok gracias pero ya lo solucione gracias a @ElChiniNet

Comment: Perfecto @LuisAngelMezaPerez, ahora sí verifica que estén seleccionados todos. Un saludo ;)

Comment: Se agradece el aporte @ElChiniNet, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Debes darle un nombre distinto a cada checkbox, ya que al tener el mismo lo vas sobrescribiendo. 
También puedes ponerles una misma clase css y recogerlos por la clase, para luego recorrer los elementos

Comment: Hola Carmen. Veo que has rechazado mi edición. Si puedes corrige tú misma el error ortográfico: https://is.gd/yx0re5

Comment: Gracias @ElChiniNet, la rechacé porque me parecía que la abundancia de etiquetas disminuía la claridad del texto, aunque sé que para editar una pregunta hace falta un mínimo de cambios. Se me había pasado la 'e' de más, corregida :).

Comment: Exactamente Carmen, no podía editar solamente eso, el sistema me pedía introducir más cambios. Un saludo ;)

Answer (score 0):

A continuación te muestro la forma de hacerlo con `jQuery`:

```
var estado = true;

$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
    var myCheck = $(this).prop('checked');
    if(!myCheck){
        estado = false;
    }
});
```

De esta forma si alguno no está seleccionado, el resultado será **FALSE**, todos deben estar seleccionados para que la respuesta sea **TRUE**.